# MS Access VBA Me.Recordset.Findfirst Runtime Error

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

I've got a Problem with one of my vba Events.

Firstly, the event triggers after a change in a field is made, that field belongs to a form which shows multiple data entrys from one table, this form sits inside a NavigationPane.

My database is being programmed in access 2016 32bit and will be mostly used by our workers on an server with Access Runtime 2013

Now when I trigger the event on my pc everything works as intended, but on the server Runtime version it shows me an Error, which i will try to translate into English, for i am in Germany: "The Execution of this program cant continue, due to a runtime Error" - "This Program cant continue to run and will be closed".

I already tried looking through the duck but couldnt find what i need, mostly due to the keyword "Runtime" having two different meanings in this context.

Here's the Code:

```
Private Sub isEnd_AfterUpdate()
Dim isEnd As Date
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim strFind As String
Dim test As Variant

'On Error Resume Next

Set rs = Recordset

With rs
If Not .EOF Then
        isEnd = Me!isEnd
    If Me!isStart > 0 Then
        Me!isDur = (Me!isEnd - Me!isStart) * 24
    End If

    strFind = "IdMa = '" & Me!IdMa & "' and OrderRow = " & Me!OrderRow + 1
    'test = MsgBox(strFind & " - " & rs.Name & " - '" & isEnd & "'", vbOKOnly, "test")
    Me.Recordset.FindFirst (strFind)
    Me!isStart = isEnd
    Me.isEnd.SetFocus
End If
End With
End Sub
```

You may ignore the Error Handling and MsgBox which i tried to use for Debugging.

The Database is for Planning our Processes and this field keeps the endtime of the finished process and should enter it into the starttime of the next process, to save a little bit of time.

Edit1:
I should mention that i pinpointed the Error down to the line:

```
Me.Recordset.Findfirst (strFind)
```

but cant figure out why this is a problem, the exact same line is used just fine in some Buttons on the same Form.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the line 'Set rs = Recordset'

Comment: Its supposed to refer to the recordset inside my form, which does work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the RecordsetClone and don't duplicate the control names:

```
Private Sub isEnd_AfterUpdate()

    Dim isEndDate As Date
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strFind As String
    Dim test As Variant

    'On Error Resume Next

    Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone

    With rs
        If Not .EOF Then
            isEndDate = Me!isEnd
            If Me!isStart > 0 Then
                Me!isDur = (Me!isEnd - Me!isStart) * 24
            End If

            strFind = "IdMa = '" & Me!IdMa & "' and OrderRow = " & Me!OrderRow + 1
           'test = MsgBox(strFind & " - " & .Name & " - '" & isEnd & "'", vbOKOnly, "test")
            .FindFirst strFind
            ' and use the found record for something ..?

            Me!isStart.Value = isEndDate
            Me!isEnd.SetFocus
        End If
        .Close
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I do use it for the later injection of my isEndDate Value and Focussing the next Field. I dont have time for testing this right now, but will come back to it next Week, thanks.